# sort csv file by year using dictionary (Python 3.X)

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I have a csv file with movie data that is something like this (sample):

```
year revenue
2013 3000
2013 4000
2013 5000
2012 1500
2012 3000
2011 2000
2011 1000
```

I want to create a new csv file that has the following info:

```
year year_freq total_rev
2013 3         12000
2012 2         4500
2011 2         3000
```

Etc.

This is my code so far (only started with handling year frequency)... I'm stuck.

```
import csv
from collections import Counter
i=0
nummovies={}
yearrev={}
with open ('movies.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
for line in csv_reader:
    try:
        if line['year'] in nummovies:
            nummovies[line['year']]+=1
        else:
            nummovies=line['year']
    except ValueError:
            i=0
for key,value in nummovies.items():
    print(key,value)

print(i)
```

Comment: provide sample data and expected output

Comment: @KenDekalb: That was provided, though the expected output was not complete (it is missing one line) and the formatting was so poor that it was difficult to see. The formatting has been improved and I added the missing line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to achieve this.

First thing to do is to analyze what we are trying to achieve here, and outline the work we need to do:

1. read data (I will "mock" this step, as you have already implemented it yourself)
2. collect stats
3. write the stats to a file

As a way to keep things clean, we could create a "main" function that would do just that:

```
def analyze_movie_data():
    data = read_data()
    stats = get_stats(data)
    write_stats_to_csv(stats)
```

The implementation details then follow. Note that I also created a helper method for collecting the stats line by line - again, so that I don't have to keep to much logic in my head at a single time.

---

```
from csv import DictWriter

def read_data():
    lines = [
        {'year': 2011, 'revenue': 1000},
        {'year': 2012, 'revenue': 2000},
        {'year': 2011, 'revenue': 3000},
        {'year': 2012, 'revenue': 4000},
        {'year': 2011, 'revenue': 5000},
    ]
    return lines


def get_stats(lines):

    def add_line(stats, line):
        year = line['year']

        if year not in stats:
            stats[year] = {'year': year, 'freq': 0, 'total_revenue': 0}

        stats[year]['freq'] += 1
        stats[year]['total_revenue'] += line['revenue']

    stats = {}
    for line in lines:
        add_line(stats, line)
    return stats


def write_stats_to_csv(stats):
    columns = ['year', 'freq', 'total_revenue']

    with open('stats.csv', 'w', newline='') as output:
        writer = DictWriter(output, columns)
        writer.writeheader()
        for year in stats:
            writer.writerow(stats[year])



def analyze_movie_data():
    data = read_data()
    stats = get_stats(data)
    write_stats_to_csv(stats)

analyze_movie_data()
```

The output is then (for my mocked input):

```
year,freq,total_revenue
2011,3,9000
2012,2,6000
```

Answer (score 0):

@lessreg: Assuming the data is:

```
data = 2013, 3000, 2013, 4000, 2013, 5000, 2012, 1500, 2012, 3000, 2011, 2000, 2011, 1000
```

We can write the following code

```
years = [data[x] for x in range(len(data)) if x % 2 == 0]
revenues = [data[x] for x in range(len(data)) if x % 2 == 1]

def reorder(year, rev):
    YEARS = year.copy()
    REVENUE = rev.copy()
    ans = []
    for year in YEARS:
        count = YEARS.count(year)
        total_rev = 0
        for i in range(count):
            j = YEARS.index(year)
            total_rev += REVENUE[j]
            del YEARS[j], REVENUE[j]
        ans.extend([year, count, total_rev]
    return ans
```

Answer (score 0):

I provide an easy to read and understand solution.

Since you are grouping by the years it only makes sense, to use it as the key. The values in the dictionary are of a comlex type, since they has two properties. The simplest form of grouping them together is by using tuples. (More complex cases can have classes, with various business logic implemented on them.).

You try to acces the record for the year, and increment the counter, and update the revenue. If there is no data, initalize the counter and revenue with 0.

```
collector = {}
for year, revenue in zip(years, revenues):
    count, total = collector.setdefault(year, (0,0)) # will return (0,0) if year is not already in the dictionary
    count += 1
    total += revenue
    collector[year] = (count, total)
```